# After creating div elements, how is it that they may be undefined when trying to manipulate them in the Dom?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```js
    var initialCircle;
    var i;
    var randomXPos;
    var randomYPos;
    var colorArray;
    colorArray=[
        'aliceblue','lavender','powderblue','lightblue','lightskyblue','skyblue','deepskyblue','lightsteelblue',    'dodgerblue','cornflowerblue','steelblue','cadetblue','mediumslateblue','slateblue','darkslateblue','royalblue','blue','mediumblue','darkblue','navy','midnightblue','blueviolet',  'indigo'];
    var randomColor;
    function startBouncingHoverCircles(){for(i=0;i<5;i++){randomXPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1200) + 200;randomYPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1200) + 200;randomColor=colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArray.length)];initialCircle = document.createElement('div');document.body.appendChild(initialCircle);initialCircle.className="circles";initialCircle.style='height:100px;width:100px;border-radius:50%;box-sizing:border-box;position:absolute;border:3px solid green;background-color:'+randomColor;initialCircle.style.top=randomYPos+'px';initialCircle.style.left=randomXPos+'px';setTimeout(function(){document.getElementsByClassName("circles").style.transition="transform 1s";document.getElementsByClassName("circles").style.transform="translate(5px, 5px)"},500)}}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/randomcolor/0.6.1/randomColor.min.js" integrity="sha512-vPeZ7JCboHcfpqSx5ZD+/jpEhS4JpXxfz9orSvAPPj0EKUVShU2tgy7XkU+oujBJKnWmu4hU7r9MMQNWPfXsYw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <button onClick="startBouncingHoverCircles()">Start</button>
    <script src="../Js/bouncingHoverCircles.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I create twenty five circles by using a for loop and looping through twenty five times. I set within the loop a class name, and I can physically see that the class name is attached to each circle. I'm wondering why when I try to manipulate each element by their class name, the program responds with undefined when trying to get Element by Class Name.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your original code and I confirmed that right result is displayed.
I recommend that you will confirm again.

Comment: the result shown in the snippet is showing an error of undefined is it not?

Comment: @mathewstratton: For me, your snippet returns 25 rows with numbers, followed by 25 rows with nondescript “script errors”.

Comment: @JeremyCaney I edited and took out the console of the twenty five numbers and changed it to 5 circles so its more agreeable. so now its 5 errors of undefined. the goal is translate these circles across the screen when the timeout function is called by getting all the elements with the same class, (".circles")

Comment: I think it may be that Im using border radius so the browser my not be picking up the circles by their classes because they are not recognized. what browsers are yall using?

Comment: my previous comment was not the case, i tried making them squares and im still being thrown undefined